# Perl not able to tail rotated log file

Tags: perl, logging

I am using property based filters of rsyslog to send specific logs to seperate file where those logs will be parsed using perl.

This is my rsyslog entry

```
$template SPLIT,"/home/shivam/hello-%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%%$HOUR%%$MINUTE%"
:msg, contains, "hello" -?SPLIT
```

So rsyslog will create separate files for logs coming after every minute. Files will be created like this `hello-201505281139`.

My perl script to parse these files is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d%H%M", localtime;
my $file = '/root/defer-'.$date;
open(my $fh,'<',$file) or die "unable to open file $!\n";

while(1) {
    while(my $line = <$fh>){
                    print "$date\n";
                    print "$line";
            }
    sleep(2);
    unless ($date == strftime "%Y%m%d%H%M", localtime) {
            close($fh);
            $date = strftime "%Y%m%d%H%M", localtime;
            $file = '/root/defer-'. $date;
            system("touch $file");      
            open(my $fh,'<',$file) or die "unable to open file $!\n";

    }
}
```

In unless block i am checking that if minute has changed then i close previous file and open new file. 
The reason i am creating new file from script and not waiting for rsyslog to create file is that the frequency of logs coming is not that much. So i create file and just start reading on it in hope that when any new log will come i will be able to read that.

But what is happening is that i am able to create new file but not able to read anything from that file.

This is what i am getting as warning

`readline() on closed filehandle $fh at test.pl line 14.`

Line 14 in my code is this line
`while(my $line = <$fh>){`

I am not able to see anything wrong in my code. Please suggest what is the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different `$fh` lexical (my) variables,

So instead declaring new one

```
open(my $fh,'<',$file) or die "unable to open file $!\n";
```

keep using previously declared one,

```
open($fh,'<',$file) or die "unable to open file $!\n";
```

Comment: I open file in different $fh variable and i keep on reading from previously closed one thus causing all troubles. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: @shivams yes, please check [`Variable hidden by other declaration`](http://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl)

Comment: Thanks i was really bugged by the issue and never realize that this is my problem. Thanks again.